# How to use CombineFileInputFormat in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to use the CombineFileInputFormat of Hadoop 0.20.0 / 0.20.2 such that it processes 1 file per record and also doesn't compromise on data - locality (which it normally takes care of).

It is mentioned in Tom White's Hadoop Definitive Guide but he has not shown how to do it. Instead, he moves on to Sequence Files.

I am pretty confused on what is the meaning of processed variable in a record reader. 
Any code example would be of tremendous help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `one file per record`?

Answer (score 2):

Check the below input format used to combined file input format.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader;


/**
 * CustomInputformat which implements the createRecordReader of abstract class CombineFileInputFormat
 */

public class MyCombineFileInputFormat extends CombineFileInputFormat {

    public static class MyRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable,Text>{
        private LineRecordReader delegate=null;
        private int idx;

        public MyRecordReader(CombineFileSplit split,TaskAttemptContext taskcontext ,Integer idx) throws IOException {
            this.idx=idx;
            delegate = new LineRecordReader();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            delegate.close();
        }

        @Override
        public float getProgress() {
            try {
                return delegate.getProgress();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext taskcontext) throws IOException {
            CombineFileSplit csplit=(CombineFileSplit)split;
            FileSplit fileSplit = new FileSplit(csplit.getPath(idx), csplit.getOffset(idx), csplit.getLength(idx), csplit.getLocations());
            delegate.initialize(fileSplit, taskcontext);
        }

        @Override
        public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            return delegate.getCurrentKey();
        }


        @Override
        public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return delegate.getCurrentValue();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return delegate.nextKeyValue();
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public RecordReader createRecordReader(InputSplit split,TaskAttemptContext taskcontext) throws IOException {
        return new CombineFileRecordReader((CombineFileSplit) split, taskcontext, MyRecordReader.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to use CombineFileInputFormat from the so-called "new API".  Suppose your actual input format is *MyFormat*, and it works with keys of *MyKey* and values of *MyValue* (might be some subclass of `SequenceFileInputFormat< MyKey, MyValue >`, for example).

```
public class CombinedMyFormat extends CombineFileInputFormat< MyKey, MyValue > {
    // exists merely to fix the key/value types and
    // inject the delegate format to the superclass
    // if MyFormat does not use state, consider a constant instead
    private static class CombineMyKeyMyValueReaderWrapper
    extends CombineFileRecordReaderWrapper< MyKey, MyValue > {
        protected CombineMyKeyMyValueReaderWrapper(
            CombineFileSplit split, TaskAttemptContext ctx, Integer idx
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            super( new MyFormat(), split, ctx, idx );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader< MyKey, MyValue > createRecordReader(
        InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext ctx
    ) throws IOException {
        return new CombineFileRecordReader< MyKey, MyValue >(
            ( CombineFileSplit )split, ctx, CombineMyKeyMyValueReaderWrapper.class
        );
    }
}
```

In your job driver, you should now be able to just drop in `CombinedMyFormat` for `MyFormat`.  You should also set a [max split size property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556282/combinefileinputformat-launches-only-one-map-always-hadoop-1-2-1) to keep Hadoop from combining the entire input into a single split.