# CombineFileInputFormat launches only one map always Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to use test CombineFileInputFormat to process few small files (20 files) of 8 MB each. I followed the sample given in this [blog](http://yaseminavcular.blogspot.in/2011_03_01_archive.html). I am able to implement and test it. The end result is correct. But what is surprising to me is that it is always ending up with only one map. I tried setting the attribute "mapred.max.split.size" various values like 16MB, 32MB etc (Of course in bytes) without any success. Is there anything else I need to do or is it the right behavior?

I am running a two node cluster with default replication as 2. Given below is the code that developed. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
package inverika.test.retail;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class CategoryCount {

    public static class CategoryMapper
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>    {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private String[] columns = new String[8];

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws     IOException, InterruptedException {
            columns = value.toString().split(",");  
            context.write(new Text(columns[4]), one);
        }
    }

    public static class CategoryReducer
        extends Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>    {

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable>  values, Context context)
                throws     IOException, InterruptedException {

                int sum = 0;

                for (IntWritable value :  values) {
                        sum += value.get();
                }
               context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception    {
        if (args.length != 2)  {
                System.err.println("Usage: CategoryCount <input Path> <output Path>");
                System.exit(-1);
        } 

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
        conf.set("mapred.max.split.size", "16777216");   // 16 MB

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Retail Category Count");
        job.setJarByClass(CategoryCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(CategoryMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CategoryReducer.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(CombinedInputFormat.class);
        //CombineFileInputFormat.setMaxInputSplitSize(job, 16777216);
        CombinedInputFormat.setMaxInputSplitSize(job, 16777216);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]) );
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]) );
        //job.submit();
        //System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(false) ?  0 : 1);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ?  0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Here is the CombinedFileInputFormat implemented

```
package inverika.test.retail;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat;

public class CombinedInputFormat extends CombineFileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text>
            createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
                    throws IOException {

        CombineFileRecordReader<LongWritable, Text> reader = 
                new CombineFileRecordReader<LongWritable, Text>(
                        (CombineFileSplit) split, context, myCombineFileRecordReader.class);        
        return reader;
    }

    public static class myCombineFileRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
        private LineRecordReader lineRecordReader = new LineRecordReader();

        public myCombineFileRecordReader(CombineFileSplit split, 
                TaskAttemptContext context, Integer index) throws IOException {

            FileSplit fileSplit = new FileSplit(split.getPath(index), 
                                                split.getOffset(index),
                                                split.getLength(index), 
                                                split.getLocations());
            lineRecordReader.initialize(fileSplit, context);
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(InputSplit inputSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            //linerecordReader.initialize(inputSplit, context);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            lineRecordReader.close();
        }

        @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException {
            return lineRecordReader.getProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            return lineRecordReader.getCurrentKey();
        }

        @Override
        public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return lineRecordReader.getCurrentValue();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return lineRecordReader.nextKeyValue();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small question: how do you count the number of map tasks? (reason I ask: it's possible to interprete some of the output wrongly)
Another small one: Are you setting any hadoop environment parameters, like the number of map slots in a tasktracker?

Comment: Number of Map tasks will be given in the Job output counters. Number of map slots per TaskTracker I am going with the default of two.

Comment: Can you add a system.out to your map function, just to make sure it runs only once? The result will be in the logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the maximum split size when using the `CombineFileInputFormat` as the input format class. Or you would probably get exactly **ONLY ONE** mapper when all blocks come from the same rack.

You can achieve this in one of the following ways:

- call the [`CombineFileInputFormat.setMaxSplitSize()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.html#setMaxSplitSize(long)) method
- set `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` or <del>`mapred.max.split.size`</del>(deprecated) configuration parameter
  For exmaple, by issuing the following call

  ```
  job.getConfiguration().setLong("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize", (long)(256*1024*1024));
  ```

  you are setting the maximum split size to 256MB.

reference:

- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.html
- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/201004.mbox/%3C35374.30384.qm@web63402.mail.re1.yahoo.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

If a maxSplitSize is specified while using CombineFileInputFormat, then blocks on the same node are combined to form a single split  so in your scenario all the files appears to be on same node hence they are constituting to a single split only.  Hence a single Mapper.

you can refer to CombineFileInputFormat Doc for more details 
             https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html